# Setup local Selenium project to run with Jenkins installed on Docker container

Tags: docker, selenium-chromedriver

We have a local Selenium project for testing the a website's UI (using ChromeDriver). For now we are using a separate laptop to do this runs, but we want to transform this laptop into a server, to be able to access Jenkins from the outside and start the tests. So far I managed to download the Jenkins image, install, downloaded the latest chromium and chromedriver, copy the project on the linux container and try to run it using `mvn-post-integration-test` command but we get this error:

```
SEVERE: org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Execution failed (Exit value: -559038737. Caused by java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/var/jenkins_home/workspace/JenkinsProject/drivers/linux/chromedriver" (in directory "."): error=2, No such file or directory)
[pool-1-thread-1] ERROR net.thucydides.core.webdriver.WebDriverFacade - FAILED TO CREATE NEW WEBDRIVER_DRIVER INSTANCE class org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver: Could not instantiate new WebDriver instance of type class org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver (Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '3.13.0', revision: '2f0d292', time: '2018-06-25T15:24:21.231Z'
System info: host: '9c8af7675c2e', ip: '172.17.0.2', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.9.93-boot2docker', java.version: '1.8.0_171'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
net.thucydides.core.webdriver.UnsupportedDriverException: Could not instantiate new WebDriver instance of type class org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver (Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
Build info: version: '3.13.0', revision: '2f0d292', time: '2018-06-25T15:24:21.231Z'
System info: host: '9c8af7675c2e', ip: '172.17.0.2', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '4.9.93-boot2docker', java.version: '1.8.0_171'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
```

My company forbids us from using gitlab so we need to get the project from out local machines always.
Now my questions are:
1. What might be the problem with the stacktrace I presented? I mention that also running on root gives me the same error.
2. What might be the correct approach to deploy our jenkins + selenium project which runs chrome (using ChromeDriver, not RemoteWebDriver) in headless mode on a Docker container taking the source project from out laptop (not from a subversion tool)?
Thanks!

Comment: the error states that the chromedriver cannot be located at the given path `/var/jenkins_home/workspace/JenkinsProject/drivers/linux/chromedriver`. please check where the chromedriver executable is located and set the path to it accordingly: http://chromedriver.chromium.org/getting-started

Comment: It is already there:bash-4.4# pwd
/var/jenkins_home/workspace/JenkinsProject/drivers/linux
bash-4.4# ls
chromedriver  geckodriver
bash-4.4# whoami
root